# How to handle convLSTM for multiple points?

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm

I have created ConvLSTM model but the data pre-processing is challenging.

My train_df is (384,5979), where 384 rows represent; features as timeseries (first 192 rows), and targets as timeseries (last 192 rows). I have 5979 columns, each represent a different location on a map. I want to predict `T` for n_future=5 from n_past=10 for each location. Q:feature, each number represent timesteps. T: target, each number for timesteps

```
train_df.head(5)
Out[143]: 
        0         1     2         3     ...     5975     5976     5977     5978
Q1  0.065599  0.188100   0.0  0.065543  ...  2.13404  2.13746  2.13837  2.13740
Q2  0.066700  0.170399   0.0  0.066664  ...  1.99099  1.99418  1.99503  1.99412
Q3  0.066700  0.155400   0.0  0.066679  ...  1.85665  1.85962  1.86041  1.85957
Q4  0.065599  0.142799   0.0  0.065587  ...  1.73130  1.73407  1.73481  1.73402
Q5  0.063801  0.132200   0.0  0.063796  ...  1.61506  1.61766  1.61835  1.61761

[5 rows x 5979 columns]

train_df.tail(5)
Out[144]: 
          0         1         2     3     4     ...  5974  5975  5976  5977  5978
T188  0.000001  2.270323  0.072097   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
T189  0.000001  2.252760  0.071177   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
T190  0.000001  2.234907  0.070079   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
T191  0.000001  2.217203  0.068883   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
T192  0.000001  2.199685  0.067683   0.0   0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

What can be the size of X_train and y_train in that case?